# Multiple Javascript Closures & Naming Practices Have me all turned around

Tags: javascript, closures

Working with multiple closures has me all turned around. It seems that you define a variable in one closure then return it publicly so it can be accessed. Returning it requires giving it a public name. Then you pull it into another closure by defining it as a new variable with yet a third name?

My head is spinning a bit.

Here's a code snippet. It obviously doesn't work (obvious to you maybe, I had to struggle to get this far) Where am I breaking down? AM I making this too difficult on myself? Is there a simpler way or merely a 'best practice' way?

If this is the correct course... I'll commit to it. I'm not looking for an easy answer, but I am looking to truly grasp what I'm doing rather than regurgitate structures I've seen somewhere already. Thanks in advance.

```
//CREATES A PRIVATE CLOSURE TO GRAB DOM CLASS & ASSOCIATED VALUE
var createUI = (function(){

    //Stores a class from DOM into VARIABLE
    var buttonClass = ".add__btn";

    //RETURNS...
    return {
        // THE VALUE FOUND IN THE DOM ELEMENT OF THE STORED CLASS ABOVE
        classPublicValue : function(){
            return {
                value: document.querySelector(buttonClass).value
            }
        },
        // RETURNS THE CLASS ITSELF FOR FUTURE SHORTHAND USAGE. A GOOD PRACTICE I'M TOLD??
        theClass : function() {
            return buttonClass;
        }

    }

})();

//CREATES A SECOND PRIVATE CLOSURE TO PERFORM ACTION ON CLICK THAT USING STRUCTURES FROM FIRST CLOSURE.
var clickToHappen = (function() {

    //PULLS IN THE CLASS ".add__Btn" as a string.
    var myClass = createUI.theClass();
    //POINTS TO THE VALUE OF THE ELEMENT CONTAINING THE PULLED IN CLASS.
    var myValue = createUI.classPublicValue();


    //RETURNS...
    return{
        clickMe : function(){
            //A CLICK LISTENER ON DOM ELEMENT WITH CLASS CHOSEN IN FIRST PRIVATE CLOSURE.
            document.querySelector(myClass).addEventListener('click', function() {
                //STORES CURRENT VALUE INTO VARIABLE
                var value = createUI.classPublicValue();
                //PRINTS THAT VALUE TO CONSOLE
                console.log(value);
            });
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: You seem to never call the actual `clickMe` function. Try adding `clickToHappen.clickMe();` at the end so that the event handler is added. If you really just want to add an event listener on a button I would say that these closures are unneccessary. Just use `document.querySelector(...).addEventListener(...)` and you're done.

Comment: Thank you. Producing the simple act of adding an eventListener wasn't the goal. It was merely the example I put into the code. I was having trouble figuring out how to handle closures and the multiple names they can acquire when being brought into other closures.

I've since realized I can just keep the public method names the same and then import them into the new closure using the same name as well. Much easier to follow, but is this bad practice?